# Notice of Violation of Facebook Audience Network Policy - This placement encourages accidental ad clicks

Tags: android, ads, facebook-ads-api

I have an Android app and I have integrated Facebook ads in it. In the app I have an activity which has next and previous button. On clicking the next or the previous button the content changes.

I display Interstitial ad when the user clicks on next or previous button four times i.e. after 4 clicks on next or previous the ad is displayed.

Today I got mail from Facebook stating that this placement encourages accidental ad clicks and hence the ads are removed.

So I wanted to know what can I do to fix this or the only option I have is to show banner ads?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Facebook policy and not about programming